# Como se diz «spoiler» em português?

Tags: tradução-inglês, estrangeirismos

Um "[*spoiler*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spoiler_(media))" é um comentário que revela pormenores do enredo de uma narrativa — como um livro, um filme, etc.

> Spoiler (media), comment that discloses plot details of a book, play, video game, film, or other narrative content.

Como se diz isto em português?

O conceito central é que ao ser dado a conhecer este pormenor, este "spoiler", isso altera a experiência pura de descobrir a trama/enredo naturalmente, altera o consumo dessa narrativa, evitando ou até estragando essa experiência.
Por exemplo, a leitura de uma história de Hercule Poirot fica profundamente alterada se soubermos que o assassino foi o mordomo, na biblioteca, com o candelabro.

O dicionário priberam [tem a palavra spoiler](https://dicionario.priberam.org/spoiler) como estrangeirismo.
Mas de que maneira se pode dizer isto sem usar este estrangeirismo?

> - Ainda não vi a série The Expanse, evita "spoilers" sobre ela por favor.
> - Não me "spoiles" o fim, sinto que vem uma reviravolta mas não consigo perceber o que é!

> - Estou a ler *Harry Potter e o Enigma do Príncipe", mas já mo estragaram... ontem contaram-me o "spoiler" que o Dumbledore morre! :(

Comment: Foi morodomo?! Spoiler alert! Enfim, o Houaiss define *spoiler* como fato importante ou desfecho de trama. Antes de eu começar a ouvir *spoiler*, diziam-me "não me conta o final" ou "sem relevar o que acontece".

Comment: estraga-prazeres ou estraga-sorpresas. Tudo bem, que o pessoal use spoiler mas fazer um verbo disso? O povo sem noçã0. to spoil é simplesmente estragar.

Comment: @Lambie , não queres escrever uma resposta com essas sugestões? :)

Comment: Sem esta variabilidade, estávamos todos ainda a escrever "romani ite domum" em vez do tão belo "romanos *inde* p'ra casa"! ;-) Mas, passe a piadola, o povo é organicamente revolucionário e não se rege por estas ortodoxias centralistas...

Comment: @ANeves ortodoxias centralistas. essa é boa mesmo. :)

Comment: @ANeves Eu coloquei a resposta e você não concordou?

Answer (score 1):

Em português de Portugal podemos conjugar algumas palavras para obter o mesmo significado, por exemplo, se substituirmos a palavra *spoiler* por «[**contar**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/contar)» funciona muito bem como **verbo**, para que não façam *spoil* de um filme ou uma série:

> - Ainda não vi a série The Expanse, evita **contar** sobre ela por favor.
> - Não me **contes** o fim, sinto que vem uma reviravolta mas não
>   consigo perceber o que é!

---

Mas se quisermos usar como **adjetivo**, por exemplo:

> - Não sejas *spoiler*, não me *contes* o fim do filme.

Podemos usar o adjetivo «[**desmancha-prazeres**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/desmancha-prazeres)»:

> - Não sejas **desmancha-prazeres**, não me *contes* o fim do filme.

---

Por fim, se quisermos identificar a existência de um *spoil*, por exemplo:

> - O resumo que a revista faz do filme contém *spoilers*.

Podemos usar o verbo «[**revelar**](https://dicionario.priberam.org/revelar)»:

> - O resumo que a revista faz do filme contém revelações do mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Estraga-prazeres ou estraga-surpresa se não usar *spoiler* mesmo.

Comment: Outra vez: Deixa a minha resposta como está: @Lambie , não queres escrever uma resposta com essas sugestões? :) Não há nenhuma razão de ficar mudando o que escrevi.

Comment: Lambie, não é suposto as perguntas e respostas terem saudações nem agradecimentos, no site. Para saber mais veja [esta pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/218708).

Comment: @JorgeB. Isso não é verdade. Muitas vezes se ve no ELU uma pessoa criando uma resposta a partir de comentários de otra e agradecendo a pessoa. Outra coisa seria dizer: muito obrigado pela resposta. ISSO não. tudo bem.

Comment: @Lambie Isto é uma comunidade de estudos e de aprendizado, não uma sala de bate-papo. Chegou a ler [a pergunta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) sugerida por @JorgeB.? Se vir alguém cumprimentando e/ou agradecendo, é encorajado que se remova para manter as perguntas e respostas limpas. Por favor adeque suas respostas aos objetivos do site.

Comment: @GuiImamura It is customary on other SE sites to acknowledge a contribution from another user. No one here is chatting. And now, you  show up  here and want to teach me how to use the site?

Comment: Take a look: Both tchrist and jlawler are acknowledged. There are many many others. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/180273/is-jack-could-get-to-work-earlier-deontic-or-epistemic/181204#181204

Comment: @Lambie Acknowledging and giving credits to someone else is not the same as *thanking* someone for their help. I am not here to offend you or anyone else. Please take into account that someone else had commented about it before me and 2 other persons tried to edit it out of your answer.

Comment: @GuiImamura Both of you are wrong. Thanking is just a way of acknowleding them. It's fine. It is not my fault if people here are not familiar with SE usages, is it? It is simply not a big deal and it also avoids potential plagiarizing of someone's comments.

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler é um termo que se tornou popular em 1971 - ver Wikipédia em Inglês sob o título *Spoiler (media)* sobre a sua história.

Assim, o termo é um termo universal.

No entanto, se eu estivesse a conversar na língua portuguesa, eu diria os exemplos que você expôs do seguinte modo:

Original: "Ainda não vi a série The Expanse, evita "spoilers" sobre ela por favor."

Resposta: "Ainda não vi a série The Expanse, ***não me diga nada*** sobre isso por favor."

Original: "Não me "spoiles" o fim, sinto que vem uma reviravolta mas não consigo perceber o que é!"

Reposta: "*Não me "estragues*" o fim, sinto que vem uma reviravolta mas não consigo perceber o que é!"

Comment: Eu acho que tentar fazer um verbo em português do inglês spoil é uma locura.